# docker operator not generating any log

Tags: docker, airflow

i am facing issue with the airflow docker operator

- Docker Operator is not generating and logs.
- on the other hand Bash and Python operator working fine.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
#from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator
default_args = {
        'owner'                 : 'airflow',
        'description'           : 'Use of the DockerOperator',
        'depend_on_past'        : False,
        'start_date'            : datetime(2020, 5, 14),
        'email_on_failure'      : False,
        'email_on_retry'        : False
        #'retries'               : 1,
        #'retry_delay'           : timedelta(minutes=5)
}
with DAG('docker_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="5 * * * *", catchup=False) as dag:
        t1 = BashOperator(
                task_id='print_current_date',
                bash_command='date'
        )
        t2 = DockerOperator(
                task_id='docker_command',
                image='centos:latest',
                api_version='auto',
                auto_remove=True,
                environment={
                        'AF_EXECUTION_DATE': "{{ ds }}",
                        'AF_OWNER': "{{ task.owner }}"
                },
                command='/bin/bash -c \'echo "TASK ID (from`enter code here` macros): {{ task.task_id }} - EXECUTION DATE (from env vars): $AF_EXECUTION_DATE"\'',
                docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
                network_mode='bridge'
        )
        t3 = BashOperator(
                task_id='print_hello',
                bash_command='echo "hello world"'
        )
        t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

am i missing something on airflow configuration level?

*Entire environment is created by me.*

Comment: The issue was because of the configuration and packages we install as part of installation of airflow. this issue has been fixed now by updating the airflow latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of the configuration and packages we install as part of installation of airflow. this issue has been fixed now by updating the airflow latest version.